# Combine Values of datetime picker and combobox selected index

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I have a DateTimePicker and a ComboBox. Im trying to combine the short Date of the DateTimePicker with the selected time of the combo box.

A few combobox selections are 
12:00 AM 
12:30 AM
1:00 AM
etc.

So I have a DateTime from the datetime picker, how do I combine that with the combobox text to create a datetime class

Comment: I didnt have code, I was trying to see where the hell to start. Wasnt aware of a parse datetime function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DateTime.Parse() method:

```
var datePickerDate = dateTimePicker.Value;
var comboboxTime = comboBox.SelectedText;
var dateTimeString = String.Format("{0} {1}", datePickerDate, comboboxTime);

var combinedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeString);
```

I'm not sure if you are writing a windows or web application, but the solutions are the same. Also you might want to use one of the overloaded versions of DateTime.Parse() to have more control of the format of the stringDateTime.